# What actually happen background when an SSIS package is being created?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, msbi

Can any one explain what actually happens in the background of SQL SERVER while a SSIS Package is being created.
what does SQL SERVER actually do to create a package?

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a package using a tool such as Visual Studio.  Sql Server is not involved at all.

There are multiple deployment options.  If you deploy to a file system the package can be run with CMD, Powershell, a windows app...  In this case, again, Sql Server is not involved until the package is run.

If you deploy to MSBD the package is stored there.  This was called deploying to Sql before version 2012.

If you deploy to the Integration Services Catalog then info is stored in the SSISDB database.

There is plenty of information available on the specific details of these scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

SSIS packages are just automated processes that gives us Interactive drag and drop interface and when we do that using particular tool for a particular purpose(say importing csv file into DB) it automatically creates all coding behind the scenes like query to create table and insert commands for inserting all data from csv to DB table.